# Оператор не равно != JavaScript не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, операторы

```
let arr = [ { index: 0, symbol: 'а' }, { index: 1, symbol: 'а' } ]

arr.forEach( ( item, index ) => {

    if (item.symbol == arr[index].symbol && arr[index].index != index ){

        console.log(arr[1].symbol);  // почему то сюда  попадает arr[1].symbol;

        
    }

});
```

Comment: Доброго времени суток!
При переборе массива объектов, не получается убрать первый объект!

Comment: Надо же так удачно использовать поля и переменные :))

Comment: И снова "язык сломался", а не "я написал неработающий код, подскажите, в чем его проблема"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что они (`arr[index].index` и `index`) у Вас одинаковые:

```js
let arr = [
  { index: 0, symbol: 'а'}, 
  { index: 1, symbol: 'а'}
];

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log(index, item);
  if (item.symbol == arr[index].symbol && arr[index].index != index) {
    console.log(arr[1].symbol); 
  }
});
```

Это сравнение `item.symbol == arr[index].symbol` - бессмысленное. `item` и есть `arr[index]`.

---

```js
let arr = [
  { index: 0, symbol: 'а'}, 
  { index: 1, symbol: 'а'}
];

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (arr[0].index != index) { // or if (index != 0) {
    console.log(arr[1].symbol); 
  }
});
```

Comment: Так я таким способом хотел один из объектов оставить не напечатанным,
 0 != 0 дает false и это как раз то что мне было нужно, что бы один объект отфильтровать!

Comment: @Михаил Второй фрагмент в ответе.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!!

Answer (score 0):

Для приведенных исходных данных и не должно попадать в условие, так как значение поля `index` элемента совпадает с его индексом в массиве.

```js
let arr = [{
  index: 0,
  symbol: 'а'
}, {
  index: 1,
  symbol: 'а'
}]

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log('index', index, 'el', arr[index]);
  if (item.symbol == arr[index].symbol && arr[index].index != index) {
    console.log(arr[1].symbol); // почему то сюда не попадает arr[1].symbol;
  }
});
```

Если поменять местами элементы, все работает правильно:

```js
let arr = [{
  index: 1,
  symbol: 'а'
}, {
  index: 0,
  symbol: 'а'
}, ]

arr.forEach((item, index) => {
  console.log('index', index, 'el', arr[index]);
  if (item.symbol == arr[index].symbol && arr[index].index != index) {
    console.log(arr[1].symbol); // почему то сюда не попадает arr[1].symbol;
  }
});
```

Comment: Честно признаться пока не совсем понимаю как смена расположения объектов в массиве могла повлиять на мой if()? Большое спасибо что откликнулись на мою проблему, но сама проблема у меня заключается в том, что оператор != в условии IF у меня не срабатывает и пропускает две буквы "а", а цель пропустить дальше один символ. 
Еще раз большое спасибо!

Comment: @Михаил, в сниппете выводится индекс приходящий параметром и значение поля индекс элемента - они одинаковые, поэтому и условие не работает